# Problem when reading Fortran file with CodeBlocks IDE

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

Recently, i've begun learning Fortran programmation language.
I am using CodeBlocks IDE with GNU Fortran Compiler.

I have a problem in simple code that i found in a Fortran Course online that explains how to read and write from a file.

The program is the following:

```
program main
implicit none

character (len=14) :: c1,c2,c3
integer :: n
real :: T

open(unit=10,file='titi.txt')
read(10,*) c1,n,c2
read(10,*) c3,T
close(10)


open(unit=20,file='toto.txt')
write(20,*) c1,'il est',n,c2
write(20,*)'la',c3,'est de',T,'degres'
close(20)

end
```

Where the file 'titi.txt' contains:

```
bonjour 4   heures
temperature 37.2
```

The error message that appears in the console is the following:

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory 
 reference.

 Backtrace for this error:
 #0  ffffffff
```

I tried using the flag

```
  -g
```

And than i found using the debugger that the problem is in the first line where 'read' was used

```
  read(10,*) c1,n,c2
```

I really don't know how to deal with this. The code seems pretty simple to me and i have never seen this error message before, so i don't know what does it mean.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your responds.
Actually what caused the problem is that i was using an old compiler. So when i downloaded the last version it all worked perfectly without changing any line in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it's too much text for a comment.

It's running fine on my computer.

Can you compile it with

```
gfortran -g -O0 -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all
```

That way you should get a lot more information. Also, you can add some error checking:

Add the following variables:

```
integer :: ios
character(len=100) :: iomsg
```

Then you can add error checking to all io statements like this:

```
read(10,*) c1,n,c2
```

becomes:

```
read(10,*,iostat=ios,iomsg=iomsg) c1,n,c2
if (ios /= 0) then
    print*, "Error reading c1, n, c2:"
    print*, trim(iomsg)
    STOP
end if
```

That can also give you some hints.

Comment: At least with GFortran, the kind of IO error checking you're showing is mostly pointless. If IOSTAT= isn't present, the GFortran runtime prints out the iomsg and stops the program, which is the same as you're doing here.